# Merging a Hash to Hash Child Class - Ensure nested hash has the Child Class properties

Tags: ruby, inheritance, hash

I have a Hash Child Class where I typically want to initialize its data from another Hash and used this:

```
class ValidatedJson < Hash
    @schema = {}
    def initialize(hash = {})
        super
        JSON::Validator.validate!(@schema, hash, :validate_schema => true)
        self.update(hash)
    end

    def [](key)
        self.fetch(key)
    end
end
```

However, with self.update alone, any nested hash would be of type Hash, rather than having the properties of my child class ValidatedJson.  Anyone know of a quick efficient way of ensuring this?

Comment: Recursively converting the embedded hashes is probably the best you can do.

Comment: Yeah that's what I ended up doing...

Answer (score 2):

I'd probably emulate what ActiveSupport's `HashWithIndifferentAccess` does, which is to override `update()` as well as the constructor.

See https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/hash_with_indifferent_access.rb for their implementation.

Comment: This has come around again and going to take a harder look at HashWithIndifferentAccess.  Thanks!